# Does LINQ SELECT support System.Web.UI.AttributeCollection

Tags: linq, attributes

I'm trying to populate attributes collection in a LINQ SELECT query.

```
appointments.AddRange(db.Events.ToList().Select(appointment => new Appointment
{
    ID = appointment.ID,
    Subject = appointment.Subject,
    Attributes["Location"] = appointment.Location
}));
```

Is this supported?

Thanks.

Comment: You have not posted the entire code. However, looking at your code, it looks to be fine. are you getting any specific issues ? could you provide more details

Comment: I've found the answer. It  I'm going to use Lamda Expression to add Key to Attributes.